# change Pandas column object:time into list of string

Tags: python, pandas, string, date, time

```
data = df['time_position'] 

time_position #input data 
01:22:00
00:22:00
00:00:01
02:22:00
03:22:00
00:22:00

dtype: object
```

How can I change the object time into 'str' ?

I am hoping to change the object to str which will be then changed in to list using:

```
df['time_position'].tolist()
```

Thank you ! in advance

Comment: `str` type in pandas is also stored as `object` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.astype(str)`. Therefore:

```
df['time_position'] = df['time_position'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (if you need this only):

```
df['time_position'] = df['time_position'].str.split(":")
```

---

```
time_position
0   [01, 22, 00]
1   [00, 22, 00]
2   [00, 00, 01]
3   [02, 22, 00]
4   [03, 22, 00]
5   [00, 22, 00]
```

If you want to convert into str then use `.astype(str)`